# How to retain variable in arc in every class

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, long-polling

I have a lot of classes which are sending requests and finally it all comes to `SplitViewController`. In the `SplitUIviewclass` I have to long poll and write the data in a table view. The long polling is done in the background thread, so I have declared a variable in app delegate, but when it comes to that it is `nil`. And the problem is whenever I try to access the `NSMutablearray` through the `appdelegate`, its coming as `nil` and the array is being released. My code for long polling is

```
- (void) longPoll {

@autoreleasePool
{
//compose the request
NSError* error = nil;
NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSURL* requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/pollUrl"];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestUrl];

//send the request (will block until a response comes back)
NSData* responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                        returningResponse:&response error:&error];

//pass the response on to the handler (can also check for errors here, if you want)
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataReceived:) 
      withObject:responseData waitUntilDone:YES];
}



//send the next poll request
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(longPoll) withObject: nil];
}

- (void) startPoll {

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(longPoll) withObject: nil];
}

- (void) dataReceived: (NSData*) theData {
//i write data received here to app delegate table
}
```

If I call any other method in my SplitView class from data received, I'm losing control, also I cannot print my app delegate values in data received or the variables being released, I cannot call reload table or any other method from here.

Comment: set your property as strong/retain

Comment: Can you print "theData" in dataRecieved: method? Is it correct? If so you need to post more code.

Comment: i can print the theData in dataRecieved and sure give me some time ill post d complete problem

Answer (score 1):

Cant you set your properties in your ViewControllers as strong/retain like so

`property (strong,retain) NSMutableArray *myData;`

BTW, I learned a moment ago that it is bad practise to use your AppDelegate as a storage place for global containers. The ApplicationDelegate is a place for application delegate methods and for the initial setup of the foundation of your app; such as setting up the navigationController.

So consider storing your data in the appropriate place, perhaps core data or something else.